# Move the PDF's from folders to a "not to be sent folder" in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have about a dozen folders with up to 2500 PDF's. I need to move out 163 of the PDF's from t-SQL statement into a "not to be sent" folder in SSIS.. I already have the for each loop container and file system task.. How can I only search/select the files from my T-SQL statement to be moved?

*Note: I already have the filenames that need to be moved in my T-SQL statement*

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop container, which I assume is enumerating through the files, put a script task in front of your file system task.

The script task will check the current file name against your T-SQL results, either by running the query, or checking it against a variable that contains the results.

Then it will set a boolean variable to either true or false if the file should be moved, and in the precedence constraint leading to the file system task, you check the value of the boolean variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be asking, how do i use the TSQL statement and results from it in SSIS.

1. Create a variable filenames type ADO.Object
2. Add an execute SQL task
3. Add you TSQL to it
4. Change Result Set to Full
5. Map Result Set to @filenames
6. Add for each
7. Enumerator is Foreach ADO Enum
8. Set filenames as object
9. Map a new variable type string called filename to index 0
10. Add your file Transfer Task and use filename.

*** This assumes that filename has the full path.

Comment: Thanks Keith, went through all these steps and I keep getting an error message :  " error at file system task; @filename variable is used as a source or destination and is empty"